# Returning two different returns in an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have this function that returns an object:

```
String.prototype.test = function(a,b){
    var ob = {};
    ob[a] = b;
    return this || ob
}

//usage
"Test".test('hi','hello');
```

If `.hi` isnt attached to test, i want it to return the string.

So with that example I would need:

```
"Test".test('hi','hello').hi;//returns: hello
```

To work, but then I also need:

```
"Test".test('hi','hello'); //returns Test
```

To work, I tried using `||` in the return but it's not working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You just asked about this. You were already told that a return value can't depend on what's chained to the end of the function invocation.

Comment: If only this site had moderators...

Comment: Why downvote? He asked something using clear words. If this is a good or bad thing to do is another history. Others can see this later and learn from this question. People downvote for everything, arghh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to make the return value depend on what happens with the returned value.

You could however return a `String` object with a property `hi`:

> **Don't do this in any production code, it's extremely ugly and nobody expects it.**

```
String.prototype.doStuffThatNobodyExpects = function(a, b) {
    var s = new String(this);
    s[a] = b;
    return s;
};
```

> **Again, don't do this in any production code, it's extremely ugly and nobody expects it.**

Demo:

```
js> var s = 'Test'.doStuffThatNobodyExpects('hi', 'hello');
js> print(s);
Test
js> print(s.hi);
hello
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an ackward construction that what you want, but...

```
String.prototype.test = function(a,b){
    this[a]=b;
    return this;
}

//usage
document.write("Test".test('hi','hello'));
document.write("Test".test('hi','hello').hi);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XUcYy/
​